# Clicking on "more hot questions" results in javascript error

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, hot-questions

When I click on the link "more hot questions" a javascript error is logged to console. I´m on latest Chrome.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    (anonymous function) @ full.en.js?v=605915d08e72:4
    f.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
    h.handle.i @ jquery.min.js:3
```

How to reproduce

1. Open Developer Tools
2. Go to stackoverflow.com
3. Select "active" Tab (or any other)
4. Click on "more hot questions" -> an error is logged in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix is rolling out in next build (build rev `2015.10.28.3791` on MSE/MSO, `2015.10.28.2910` on sites).